# Effectively clear Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

This is my previous question [Clear Neo4j Embedded database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597809/clear-neo4j-embedded-database)

Right now I understand that I don't need to shutdown database, I only need to wipe all data inside of this database.

I use the following method:

```
public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
    template.query("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r", null);
}
```

but it's not work properly on a large data sets.

Also, with a new version of Spring Data Neo4j I can't use Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(db);

Is any ways to correctly and effectively clean the database state without database shutdown/deleting ?

**UPDATED**

I have implemented following util class with `cleanDb` method

```
public class Neo4jUtils {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jUtils.class);

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

    public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
        logger.info("Cleaning database");

        long count = 0;
        do {
            GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = template.getGraphDatabaseService();
            Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
            try {
                Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query("MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT " + BATCH_SIZE + " OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r RETURN count(n) as count", null);
                count = (long) result.single().get("count");
                tx.success();
                logger.info("count: " + count);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                logger.error("Error while deleting database", th);
                throw th;
            } finally {
                tx.close();
            }
        } while (count > 0);

    }

}
```

right now it hangs on the line:

```
tx.close();
```

How to fix it, what am I doing wrong ?

Also, after number of experiments I have noticed that I can clean the database as many times as I want only on the working application. Right after application restart(I kill application process from console) `cleanDb` method stops working on this existing database and hangs.

No issues in the messages.log, everything looks fine:

```
2015-07-25 23:06:59.285+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Database is now ready
```

I have no idea what can be wrong.. please help to solve this issue.

I use:

```
neo4j version 2.2.3
lucene version 3.6.2
spring-data-neo4j version 3.4.0.M1
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

**I noticed** that everything work properly if I use **`graphDatabaseService.shutdown();`** method before terminating of my application.. **Otherwise database is destroyed(Neo4j server also hangs on this corrupted db).**

Is any way to make Neo4j Embedded database more fault tolerant ?  I will lose all my data after the first error (for example blackout event) in the production environment..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works with Spring Data, but in general you should try to delete nodes/relationships in batches.

Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n, r
RETURN count(n)
```

In your application you do:

```
while return_value > 0:
    run_delete_query()
```

Depending on your memory you can of course increase the `LIMIT`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The application hangs on this query also - Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query("MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 1000 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r RETURN count(n)", null);  As you can see, I have reduced LIMIT even to 1000

Comment: OK, try 5 maybe to see if it's still a memory issue.

Comment: OK, does it work with a Cypher query in the neo4j web interface?

Comment: It works in Neo4j Web Interface - Deleted 344205 nodes, deleted 988809 relationships, statement executed in 45721 ms.

Comment: This query(with LIMIT 1000) "MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 1000 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r RETURN count(n)" works on   -Xmx512m in Neo4j Web Interface ... The full delete doesn't work even with -Xmx4g

Comment: I have updated my question, right now it hangs on tx.close()

Comment: I noticed that everything work properly if I use graphDatabaseService.shutdown(); method before terminating of my application.. Otherwise database is destroyed(Neo4j server also hangs on this corrupted db)