# Neo4j Enterprise embedded database

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm going to try Neo4j Enterprise embedded database. Right now I can't find any tutorials that explain how to configure and use Neo4j Enterprise embedded database togher with Maven and Spring.

In order to use embedded Neo4j Enterprise should I download Neo4j zip archive and start it or Maven dependency should be enough ? I don't understand collaboration between Java configuration and for example downloaded distributions.

Could you please tell me the proper way how to use Neo4j Enterprise embedded database together with my application ?

Comment: Getting started using spring data to access data in neo4j:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/  -- this is general guidance.  Please be more specific about what you're trying to do and you can probably get a better answer.

Comment: I'm going to validate this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640313/neo4j-embedded-database-hangs-after-abnormal-application-termination on Embedded Neo4j Enterprise edititon and I can't find any tutorials how to configure Embedded Neo4j Enterprise edititon instead of Embedded Neo4j Community edititon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a neo4j dependency on `org.neo4j:neo4j-enterprise:<version>`

If you don't need HA that's all you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to embed Neo4j into an application, you most likely just need the core and kernel apis which is under the org.neo4j:neo4j dependency not the enterprise dependencies (org.neo4j:neo4j-enterprise).

Your maven config would have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
  <version>NEO4J VERSION HERE</version>
</dependency>
```

Your question makes me think that you may really want to just run Neo4j as a server and connect to it via REST or any of it's BOLT drivers.  You don't download and start the embedded version - you do that with the server.  Can you clarify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This question is a little bit old. Right now I use standalone Neo4j in Docker containers

Comment: Be careful if you are using the official Neo4j Enterprise 3.3.0+ docker images. Neo4j Inc slipped in a commercial license on their dist site for versions 3.3.0 and higher.  It used to be the AGPL license.   I wrote a blog post about it:  https://blog.igovsol.com/2017/11/14/Neo4j-330-is-out-but-where-are-the-open-source-enterprise-binaries.html

Comment: Great article. Thanks!